# Solution for process.env.TZ = 'UTC' in Node for Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, postgresql, timezone, utc

I was trying to test my Postgres database to make sure everything was being added properly and would include a hardcoded date in this format `2029-01-22T16:28:32.000Z`.

Here is the table for it:

```
CREATE TABLE blogful_articles (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT,
    date_published TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

I expect to get back `2029-01-22T16:28:32.000Z` but get back `2029-01-23T00:28:32.000Z`because Windows would automatically adjust it for the timezone difference and my test would fail.

It should automatically adjust for daylight savings time but here is my solution:

```
function adjustingForTimezone(dateToAdjust) {
  const offsetInMilliseconds = dateToAdjust.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  const theDateWithOffsetAdded =
    Date.parse(dateToAdjust) - offsetInMilliseconds;
  const adjustedTime = new Date(theDateWithOffsetAdded);
  return adjustedTime;
}
```

Here is how I used it:

```
app.get("/articles", (req, res, next) => {
  const knexInstance = req.app.get("db");
  ArticlesService.getAllArticles(knexInstance)
    .then(articles => {
      const os = process.platform

      function adjustingForTimezone(dateToAdjust) {
        const offsetInMilliseconds = dateToAdjust.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
        const theDateWithOffsetAdded = Date.parse(dateToAdjust) - offsetInMilliseconds
        const adjustedTime = new Date(theDateWithOffsetAdded)
        return adjustedTime
      }

      res.json(
        articles.map(article => ({
          id: article.id,
          title: article.title,
          style: article.style,
          content: article.content,
          date_published: os === "win32" ? adjustingForTimezone(article.date_published) : new Date(article.date_published)
        }))
      );
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```

I made the `adjustingForTimezone` function that should adjust it automatically, is there any way that I could improve it?  What are the potential pitfalls of using this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach used to "adjust" for time zone doesn't actually adjust.  Instead, it creates a different point in time.  It's common to think that one can just subtract an offset to account for time zones, but those are two very different concepts.

The `Date` object has only one actual value stored within it, which is the numeric timestamp that you see when calling `getTime`, `valueOf`, `parse`, etc.   Any other functions that use the local time zone (such as `toString`), or a named time zone (such as the `timeZone` option of `toLocaleString`) will expect that the internal timestamp is UTC-based.  If it's not, then you may get incorrect results.

Where this matters in your code is where you call `getTimezoneOffset`.  The point in time you are asking for should be UTC-based, but since you need to adjust then it is already the wrong point in time.  You can test this near date/time of a DST transition and you'll see that it switches offsets slightly too early or slightly too late.

So let's go back to the original problem - you're getting a timestamp out of Postgres that has been shifted by the local time zone.  This is the culprit:

```
date_published TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
```

Here's what's probably happening:

- The `now()` function returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (aka `TIMESTAMPTZ`), using the session time zone in effect when you insert the row.  In your example, it is returning `2029-01-23T00:28:32.000+08:00`.  Thus the session time zone is probably the default, which is pulling from the server's time zone setting.  (UTC+8 - used in China, Australia, and a few other places.)
- Then you pass it to a `TIMESTAMP`, which in Postgres is *not* aware of time zone.  So it strips off the offset and stores `2029-01-23T00:28:32.000`.  Thus your timestamp is not stored in UTC but in local time.
- Later when you query, the session time zone is set to UTC, so you get back `2029-01-23T00:28:32.000Z`, which is incorrect.

There are a few different ways you could fix this:

- You could ensure the session time zone was set to `UTC` during the row insert.

  ```
    SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'; INSERT INTO ...
  ```
- You could explicitly convert to UTC before storing your timestamp when defining your table:

  ```
    date_published TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') NOT NULL
  ```
- You could define your `date_published` field as a `TIMESTAMPTZ` instead of a `TIMESTAMP`.  (This is arguably the best approach.)

  ```
    date_published TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
  ```
- You could ensure the session time zone at time of query is the same local time zone as at time of insert.  However, I don't recommend this one because you will have discrepancies if the server's time zone ever changes or if you are using a time zone that transitions between offsets for daylight saving time.

With any of these in place, you can delete your `adjustingForTimezone` function and directly use the timestamp returned from the query.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I ended up doing more research about `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMPTZ` and discovered I wasn't participating in best practices.  That was a much simpler fix than I imagined.